# Compare DateTime in Flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

I have the function below.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class DateTimeHelper {
  static DateTime format() {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    final dateFormat = DateFormat('y/M/d');
    final timeSpecific = "08:00:00";
    final completeFormat = DateFormat('y/M/d h:m:s');

    // Today Format
    final todayDate = dateFormat.format(now);
    final todayDateAndTime = "$todayDate $timeSpecific";
    var resultToday = completeFormat.parseStrict(todayDateAndTime);
    print('Today --> $resultToday'); // 2020-10-02 08:00:00.000

    // Tomorrow Format
    var formatted = resultToday.add(Duration(days: 1));
    final tomorrowDate = dateFormat.format(formatted);
    final tomorrowDateAndTime = "$tomorrowDate $timeSpecific";
    var resultTomorrow = completeFormat.parseStrict(tomorrowDateAndTime);
    print('Tomorrow --> $resultTomorrow'); // 2020-10-03 08:00:00.000

    return resultTomorrow;
  }
}
```

But I want to create if statement with the below condition.

> `If` the clock on my phone > `resultToday` (it means already past 8 in the morning) , return `resultTomorrow`, `else` return `resultToday`.

And I try this.

```
if (now > resultToday) {
  return resultTomorrow;
} else {
  return resultToday;
}
```

But that makes the error like below.

```
The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'DateTime'.
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare dates you can use `.millisecondsSinceEpoch`

```
static DateTime format() {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    print('Now --> $now');
    final dateFormat = DateFormat('y/M/d');
    final timeSpecific = "08:00:00";
    final completeFormat = DateFormat('y/M/d h:m:s');

    // Today Format
    final todayDate = dateFormat.format(now);
    final todayDateAndTime = "$todayDate $timeSpecific";
    var resultToday = completeFormat.parseStrict(todayDateAndTime);
    print('Today --> $resultToday');

    // Tomorrow Format
    var formatted = resultToday.add(Duration(days: 1));
    final tomorrowDate = dateFormat.format(formatted);
    final tomorrowDateAndTime = "$tomorrowDate $timeSpecific";
    var resultTomorrow = completeFormat.parseStrict(tomorrowDateAndTime);
    print('Tomorrow --> $resultTomorrow');

    if (now.millisecondsSinceEpoch > resultToday.millisecondsSinceEpoch) {
      print('Now after resultToday, returning tomorrow');
      return resultTomorrow;
    } else {
      print('Now before resultToday, returning today');
      return resultToday;
    }
}
```

output:

```
Now --> 2020-10-02 09:17:05.437990
Today --> 2020-10-02 08:00:00.000
Tomorrow --> 2020-10-03 08:00:00.000
Now after resultToday, returning tomorrow
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if (now > resultToday) {
  return resultTomorrow;
} else {
  return resultToday;
}
```

just use:

```
return now.isAfter(resultToday) ? resultTomorrow : resultToday;
```